# How to elegantly change the program's behavior at runtime?

Tags: android, oop, strategy-pattern

I am writing an Android game in Kotlin where the board changes according to a specific pattern - which pattern, depends on the level the user currently plays.

I need a way to use many different patterns (20, 30 at max) in my code, deciding which one of them to use at runtime.

I thought of encoding each pattern as a string, putting all these strings in a file and  at runtime loading it and parsing the desired one. However, the patterns aren't so simple, so parsing will be a complicated process. It also seems as an over-complication.

My best idea right now is writing a class for each distinct pattern (and a common parent abstract class to be used by the calling entities). Each class will have a single "apply" method that applies that specific pattern on the board.

However, it means dozens of classes (I could put them in a different folder so they don't make the main code folder too crowded), and a big switch case which maps the pattern id (received from the level manager) to the specific implementation. I'm pretty sure I don't want that.

Any better ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what may happen in future. Will there be more patterns? Are they have parts which are common? Will there be other rules, say if you have used pattern 1 then you cannot go to pattern 1 again next time and so on?

Either way you will have a dozen of patterns. Storing them as a string, object, file, model or whatever is totally up to you but you will not escape from having them. What i mean here is having 1 file with 20 patterns is not very different from having 20 files each with 1 pattern. So no, having many classes is not something that is wrong in that case.

Put them in a folder and create a facade. That way all you need to do to use them is call the facade and get apply method based on some criteria(pattern id):

The facade itself can either map id to behavior or directly checks if there is file(class) named that way in the folder. If there is one it will get instance of it and call apply method on it as a result. You can store the instance so:

**pros:**

- can be changed at any moment and behavior will change
- there will be only 1 way to present pattern ( no option to get 2 patterns trying to draw them self's )

**cons:**

- if some patterns at some point need to have one more method you need to change all of the classes and the facade

That way you don't need switch and there is no need to change the facade itself if new pattern shows up - just create new file with its own implementation and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not that ideal for SO, however, I found it really interesting. Hence I am putting some of my ideas if I had to design such game.

This is a level based game which incurs different board patterns in different levels. So it is really important that how you are designing your patterns to be translated into the board. Your pattern may have some generic keywords which can be translated into a program to create a board part by part. Let us look into an example, for making the idea clearer.

Suppose, you are building a line of pipes. Each part is being connected with the already constructed pipe. There can be a lot of differently shaped pipes in your hand. So while building a pattern, you just name each shape. For example, left-round-vertical-up, right-round-vertical-up, straight-horizontal, straight-vertical etc. You have a `Factory` class which knows the implementation of each of your shape. Now its pretty simple to store the whole pattern in your local database table. Which will be translated into your board in runtime, based on the logic your `Factory` class has.

A sample row in your database table may look like the following.

```
id      level_number     level_passed    pattern_desc
--      ------------     ------------    ------------
1            1                1          left-round-vertical-up, straight-horizontal, straight-vertical, right-round-vertical-up
2            1                0          straight-horizontal, straight-vertical, right-round-vertical-up
```

So when you have the data in the structure above in your database and you know all the keywords of your pipe segments to be translated in your board, its simpler for you to maintain the code and to add new patterns via API call.

In your current structure, its difficult to update your patterns without any application update. However, in the proposed architecture, you can easily add new patterns in different levels using a simple API call from your server. The application knows how to parse the pattern and can show them accordingly. Then your job is to call an API to get the newly introduced patterns from your server and insert them into your table for storing patterns with appropriate values.

The [factory implementation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) might require many classes, which indicates each shape of your pipe segment. However, you are not writing classes for each of your patterns which is quite a lot and difficult to manage further.

Hope that helps!